# How to use an inbound port when it has gone missing from Azure Cloud select inbound ports menu?

Tags: azure-networking, microsoft

See below, I had created a virtual machine and it failed to save or something so I went to create a new virtual machine and RDP is no longer available in the inbound port menu.
[image: Azure VM creation select inbound ports drop-down menu]

Does anyone know why this port is unavailable now?
I looked at virtual networks and looked through All Services view but I don't see anywhere where I can "free up" or unlock the RDP port.

Under [Virtual Machines](https://portal.azure.com/?quickstart=true#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResourceBlade/resourceType/Microsoft.Compute%2FVirtualMachines) I have no virtual machines so I'd love to know if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You’re not accidentally creating a Linux VM by any chance the second time?

Comment: @GregW No sir. I was very focused on Windows. I guess that might be something to watch out for though!

Comment: It'd certainly explain why RDP wasn't shown but not in your case this time.

Comment: @GregW I guess I should reproduce the problem because whatever I encountered was very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the hamburger button in the top left and Go to Virtual Networks view and click "+ Add".
2. On "Basics", "Create new" Resource group:

[image: Azure create new virtual network - Basics]

3. Under IP Addresses, make sure to select the subnet as shown. I have a default and you should too unless it was deleted previously:

[image: Azure create new virtual network - IP Addresses]

4. Thats it for the virtual network, just select defaults for the rest and **don't forget to click "Create" at the end.**
5. Now you should see that you have a new virtual network with the Resource group and Name  that you specified:

[image: azure virtual networks view]

6. Now go create a new VM using your new Resource group. This will include your new virtual network for you. RDP should be available when you look at the inbound parts drop-down menu.

[image: Select inbound ports RDP]